# PWA home screen "uninstall" DOM event

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to keep track of whether a web app has been installed to the user's home-screen using a value in `localStorage`.

I know there is [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event) that fires when a web app has been installed into a user's home-screen, but is there an event for when it has been uninstalled?

The type of event I have in mind would ideally be scheduled in a manner similar to (and behave in a manner similar to) [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event). (ie. an *uncancellable* event that allows me to schedule some last bit of work before the app is destroyed)

eg:

```js
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', function(e) {
  console.log('onappinstalled', e)
  localStorage.setItem('APP_INSTALLED', '1')
})

// given the above, is anything like the following possible?
window.addEventListener('appuninstalled', function(e) {
  console.log('onappuninstalled', e)
  localStorage.setItem('APP_INSTALLED', '0')
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised that once a user has uninstalled the app from their home-screen, the browser will begin prompting to install the app to the home-screen, again, provided you have met [the criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners#criteria).

So by using the [`onbeforeinstallprompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onbeforeinstallprompt) event, there is an opportunity to clear the `'APP_INSTALLED'` key from `localStorage`, and perform other arbitrary work.

eg:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  localStorage.removeItem('APP_INSTALLED')
})
```

Moreover, this `localStorage` key may have already been cleared if the user elected to delete all data associated with the app when uninstalling the app from their home-screen.

Comment: You can track if a PWA is installed like this, but it isn't real-time and does not trigger right away when you actually uninstall the PWA (in case you have your web app open as PWA and in the browser). This won't be an issue in most cases I assume, but would be great there would be an actual event for this.